# Como instalar modulos de PHP con Dockerfile para instancias de ElasticBeanstalk AWS

Tags: php, mysqli, docker, aws

Necesito instalar las extensiones mysqli y zip en una imagen de Docker, utilice el archivo Dockerfile para ejecutar la instalación en mis instancias pero sin ningún resultado.

este es el mi archivo Docker file:

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli mysqlnd pdo pdo_mysql zip
```

y este es el error que muestra mi sitio web:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/html/classes/ConnectionFactory.php on line 17
```

Comment: Podrías editar tu pregunta y copiar el log del build del Dockerfile. Por otra parte deberías fijarte si se ha activado la extensión viendo el resultado de [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.phpinfo.php). El link contiene un ejemplo mínimo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

La imagen que posteaste no la pude construir, corrigiendo los errores que obtenía llegué a esta imagen que sí funciona:

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    zlib1g-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql --with-mysql=mysqlnd && \
    docker-php-ext-configure mysqli --with-mysqli=mysqlnd && \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql zip && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

**NOTA:** Las última dos líneas son para intentar reducir el espacio de la imagen.

**Versión larga**
Probé construir la imagen que posteaste y me da el siguiente error:

```
+ cd /usr/src/php/ext/mysqlnd
+ phpize
Cannot find config.m4.
Make sure that you run '/usr/local/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
```

Si miramos la documentación de [MySQL Native Driver](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqlnd.install.php) vemos que dice:

> 5.4.0 El Controlador Nativo de MySQL ahora es el predeterminado para todas las extensiones de MySQL (es decir, mysql, mysqli y PDO_MYSQL).
>   Pasar mysqlnd a la configuración ahora es opcional.

Y más abajo en la misma página dice:

> Las extensiones de bases de datos MySQL deben estar configuradas para
>   utilizar la Biblioteca Cliente de MySQL. Con el fin de utilizar el
>   Controlador Nativo de MySQL, PHP necesita ser compilado especificando
>   que las extensiones de bases de datos MySQL están compiladas con el
>   soporte para el Controlador Nativo de MySQL.

Y también indica cómo compilar las extensiones, es decir, podemos sacar el paquete `mysqlnd` y necesitamos indicar que las extensiones `mysqli`y `pdo_mysql` se compilen con el MySQL Native Drive.

Para esto último puede usar `docker-php-ext-configure`.

Si agrego las líneas necesarias para configurar los paquetes, luego me dá el error de que no encuentra `zlib` para compilar la extensión zip:

```
checking libzip... no
checking for the location of zlib... configure: error: zip support requires ZLIB. Use --with-zlib-dir=<DIR> to specify prefix where ZLIB include and library are located
```

Por lo que estaría faltando instalar el paquete `zlib1g-dev` para compilar `zip`. Agregándolo la instalación del paquete y luego haciendo limpieza de los paquetes, llego a la imagen de arriba.